# How do check for accounts older than a certain date in mysql and php?

Tags: mysql, date

I'm setting up a cleanup on accounts in my database, and only want to run it on accounts that haven't been checked for cleaning in the last 3 months.

Once an account has been checked, regardless if it gets cleaned, I save the date that it's been checked in the following format eg 2019-05-29

When checking for accounts that need to be cleaned, how do I write the

```
WHERE `accountLastCheckedDate` > 3 months
```

part of the query please?

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `accountLastCheckedDate` older than today minus 3 months

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE accountLastCheckedDate < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH)
```

or newer?

```
WHERE accountLastCheckedDate >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you, gl hf

```
Select * FROM My Table where columname>=DATEADD(m, -3, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Thank you everyone! That's got it up and running!

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in date and time:

```
WHERE `accountLastCheckedDate < `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
```

If you are interested in just the date:

```
WHERE `accountLastCheckedDate` < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
```